# Why is JavaScript DOM color manipulation not working?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to code a program where the user inputs an emotion and it makes the background color a color prechosen by me. My code is:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      var feeling = prompt("Enter an emotion.");
      if (feeling == "ANGRY") {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
      } else if (feeling == "HAPPY") {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
      } else if (feeling == "SAD") {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
      } else if (feeling == "DISGUSTED") {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
      } else if (feeling == "HUNGRY") {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "purple";
      } else if (feeling == "ENJOYING") {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
      } else if (feeling === "LAZY") {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
      } else if (feeling == "STRESSFUL") {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "DarkBlue";
      } else {
        alert(
          "That feeling is not documented. Please try again with a documented feeling."
        );
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, everytime I run it in Edge, it throws this error:

```
main.html:49 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
at main.html:49
```

All other answers were not giving me control of the backgroundColor. What should I do? Anyone have any working code snippets that I could use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the javascript code bellow/inside the body tag

The reason is that when trying to make the request for the emotion the renderer stops to wait for your response then it is executed but the body tag has not been built and it fails because document.body is null

Please try the following example

```html
<html>
  <head> </head>
  <body>
    <p></p>
    <script>
      var feeling = prompt("Enter an emotion.");
      if (feeling == "ANGRY") {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
      } else if (feeling == "HAPPY") {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
      } else if (feeling == "SAD") {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
      } else if (feeling == "DISGUSTED") {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
      } else if (feeling == "HUNGRY") {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "purple";
      } else if (feeling == "ENJOYING") {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
      } else if (feeling === "LAZY") {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
      } else if (feeling == "STRESSFUL") {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "DarkBlue";
      } else {
        alert(
          "That feeling is not documented. Please try again with a documented feeling."
        );
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: great that it has worked for you, if you don't mind I will appreciate if you accept the answer as correct